# Prove $(1+x)\ln(1+x) + (1-x)\ln(1-x) \leq 2x^2$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

> For all $-1<x<1$, prove:
>   $$(1+x)\ln(1+x) + (1-x)\ln(1-x) \leq  2x^2$$

I am sure we should use the Jensen's inequality or the Taylor expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ and $\ln(1-x)$; however, I was not able to do that so far. Any idea?

Comment: Apply the inequality $\log(x)\le x-1$.

Comment: After @Zvi 's attentive comment I'd like to know why you repeat (and duplicate) your own question, posted 3 months ago.

Comment: @hanno I forgot I had asked it before, and I cannot delete it now.

Comment: I think it's not a full duplicate because the Macavity's solution is different.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
If you want to use Jensen, note $\ln(1+t)$ is concave, so
$$(1+x)\ln(1+x)+(1-x)\ln(1-x) \leqslant 2\ln(1+x^2) \leqslant 2x^2$$

where the last step is from $\ln(1+t)\leqslant t$, another consequence of concavity.

Answer (score 0):

We can known that $\ln(1+x)\le x$ is True when $x > -1 $

[The polit of $y=x$ and $y=\ln(1+x)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZeZT.png)

Then$\ln(1-x)\le -x$ when $-x > -1 \Rightarrow  x < 1$

So in $-1 > x > 1 $, we can conclude that

$(1+x)\ln(1+x) + (1-x)\ln(1-x) \le (1+x)x + (1-x)(-x) = 2x^2$

Prove done, good luck to you